# Can I place a bathroom vent fan lower on a wall if I increase the CFM?

Tags: bathroom, venting

I know it is ideal to mount a bathroom vent fan on the ceiling, or as high up the wall as possible (steam rises, right?). However, due to physical constraints of running the ductwork the only place I have to install it is about 2/3 of the way up the wall.

Will over-powering the fan, maybe with a 200+ CFM motor make up for this less than ideal placement?

If it matters, the run to the exterior is about 8-10 feet, possibly with a 1-2' drop across the run.

Also, if it matters. The main reason I am installing this now is that a member of my family likes to go in there and smoke with the door shut to keep the smoke away from the family. However, we just get hotboxed the second we open that door.  Humidity in that bathroom isn't really much of an issue.

Comment: Is there any ventilation in there now?

Comment: @user3757614 There is currently no ventilation in the bathroom.

Answer (score 1):

I think you stand a good chance of being satisfied with 200+ cfm's.  Keep your venting duct-work full sized or larger, restrict the number of elbows. Make sure the termination does not restrict air flow.  And use a time delay timer that keeps the fan running after the smoker leaves for at least 15-minutes.